# Wordpress - Difference between wp-signup and register

Tags: wordpress, spam, spam-prevention

What is the difference between **wp-signup.php** and **wp-login.php?action=register**?

My server can't handle the register spam (over 2.000/day) on my Wordpress Network so i decided to remove the wp-signup.php file (after trying reCaptcha). Users can still register using wp-login.php?action=register. For the moment, the register spam seems to have stopped...

What is the real purpose of wp-signup.php if users can register without it?

I know this should be another question, but could you recommend me something about stopping this kind of spam on Wordpress?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's a plugin that regularly deletes the user spam and disables the notification email. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-spam-remover/ . There are other plugins to add captchas etc. Or, you can just disable public registration in the WP settings menu.

Comment: I would like to stop spam before the insert SQL query so my server won't crash. I tried captchas but i still get a lot of spam.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress

Answer (score 2):

old question but for the sake of anyone else with the problem, here's some answers I just learned.

1. Rename the wp-signup.php file to prevent bot scripts from using it. If you want to keep it functional (I do), search-replace the file name within the file and it will still work as advertised. You might need to watch when you upgrade Wordpress, I'm not sure if the upgrade process will replace the original wp-signup.php file, thus allowing bots to use it again.
2. Change your default registration link, again so bot scripts can't find it. There's a plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-registration-link/ - that lets you do that and the registration process still works. I found that I could actually use it to change the default registration link to point to my renamed wp-signup.php file, as that's the only registration path I want on my system. So, bonus.

There are more things you can do, such as creating a page template to hold the wp-signup.php forms and using that for registration, moving the wp-signup.php file into your theme folder, etc. but I don't know enough about those methods to advise you there.

Best of luck!
David